# Which functions to use in this Django logic brainteaser?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following models for a `Visitor`, `Meeting`, and a `MeetingArrival` (guest checking in).

```
class Visitor(models.Model):
    visitor_name = models.CharField(default='', max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)

class Meeting(models.Model):
    meeting_title = models.CharField(default='', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    meeting_time = models.TimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    meeting_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    hosts = models.ManyToManyField(Team, blank=False, null=False) # hosts
    expected_guests = models.ManyToManyField(Visitor, blank=False, null=False) # invited guests

class MeetingArrival(models.Model):
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(Visitor)
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting)
    arrival_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I already have a visitor.id stored in the session `session_visitor = Visitor.objects.get(id=request.session['visitor_id'])`. In `Meeting`, `hosts` is a list of employees who are hosting the meeting, and `expected_gusts` is a list of pre-registered visitors.

What is the simplest approach (ie which functions/methods should I use) to:

1. allow a `visitor` to select a `host` (I assume via a `selectfield` on the `Meeting` model?),
2. check if that `visitor` is listed as an `expected guest` for a `meeting` instance with that `host`, (should I use a `through`? how would this work?)
3. select the qualifying `Meeting` with the closest `meeting_time` to the current time (assuming there may be more than one) and create a `MeetingArrival` based on that `meeting` for that `visitor`.

Code examples would be really helpful! Thanks

Comment: couldn't the `MeetingArrival` be the 'through model' of a ManyToMany relation between `Visitor` and `Meeting` ?

Comment: I want the visitor to select a `host` (one of which there may be many for a `meeting`), not the `meeting_id`, and then the logic shown to select the `meeting` (based on if the visitor is an expected guest, closest matcvhing time etc). How would the `through model` work to achieve this?

Comment: the through model won't achieve that, you'll have to think about the problem and write some code to achieve that. the through model is just making the implicit m2m relation you've currently got into an explicit one

Comment: have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield